# jdk1.7.0 installation on ubuntu 10.10

Tags: java, ubuntu

I am new to ubuntu 10.10 and am using it as VM. I tried installing jdk 1.7 to run java programs from terminal. I followed the instructions from the link: [How to Install Oracle Java on Ubuntu Linux](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux). After installation was complete, i tried to test run a Hello World java program. The program compiled successfully when i did `javac Hello.java`. However when i tried to run the program using `java Hello`, it didnt give any output on the terminal and gave me the following:

> Unable to launch the application.

Exception:

```
CouldNotLoadArgumentException[ Could not load file/URL specified: Hello]
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Wrapped Exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Hello (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Further i tried checking my version for `java` using `java -version` and it gave the following output:

```
 Java(TM) Web Start 10.0.0.147-fcs 
Usage:  javaws [run-options] <jnlp-file>    
        javaws [control-options]        
    where run-options include:          
  -verbose          display additional output   
  -offline          run the application in offline mode 
  -system           run the application from the system cache only
  -Xnosplash        run without showing a splash screen 
  -J<option>        supply option to the vm 
  -wait             start java process and wait for its exit    

control-options include:    
  -viewer           show the cache viewer in the java control panel
  -clearcache       remove all non-installed applications from the cache
  -uninstall        remove all applications from the cache
  -uninstall <jnlp-file>                remove the application from the cache   
  -import [import-options] <jnlp-file>  import the application to the cache 

import-options include:                     
  -silent           import silently (with no user interface)    
  -system           import application into the system cache    
  -codebase <url>   retrieve resources from the given codebase  
  -shortcut         install shortcuts as if user allowed prompt 
  -association      install associations as if user allowed prompt
```

I see here that its using `javaws` when i try to run program using `java`.

I dont understand why this is happening or what is going wrong. Any help would be very much appreciated. Am just a beginner on Ubuntu.
Thanks in advance!!

---

**Edit 1**
Hello.java:

```
public class Hello
{
    public static void main(String... s)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World.!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to show `Hello.java`.

Comment: I have provided it in question now as an edit.

Comment: Strange, may I ask why you work with Ubuntu 10.10 (fairly outdated)? What's the output if you call java from within its installation directory?

Comment: It gives the following output:

`Hello.java:1: error: error while writing Hello: Hello.class
(Permission denied)
public class Hello
       ^
1 error`

and yes i know its fairly outdated and i'll soon upgrade.

Comment: Apologies, I meant calling `java -version` from Java installation directory...

Comment: it gives the same output as mentioned in the question.

Comment: You should do again step 18 and 19 of your tutorial. You probably linked "java" command with /usr/bin/javaws bin by mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output from `java -version` give you the ouput from javaws -version.
So this seems to be a linking error in your filesystem.
If you use update-alternatives, you create a symbolic link in your binary-folder (/usr/bin).
Maybe you had some typo while going through the tutorial?
I'm pretty sure it was something like 
`sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_05/bin/javaws" 1` or something like this.

You could try to reenter the "update-alternative" commands.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you want 10.10 when 12.04 is available. I installed the Sun/Oracle version and it worked first time. All you have to do is download it, unpack it and add it to your path.

The error message suggests Java is not installed correctly.

I suggest you also install a free IDE like IntelliJ CE.  This will make writing, compiling, running and debugging your application much easier.